# Query dictionary with linq

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a dictionary that gets built which is below

```
Dictionary<string, string> GTNMobilelist = new Dictionary<string, string>();
GTNMobilelist = LoadMobileNumbers();
```

i then need to query the Dictionary to check if a mobile number that has been enetered in to a textbox exists within the dictionary "Hope that makes sense" :-/

this is what i have

```
foreach (GridViewRow HandSetRow in grdvHandSets.Rows)
{
   TextBox txtmobileNumber = (TextBox)HandSetRow.FindControl("txtmobilenumber");

   //I need the linq statement here if the mobile number doesnt exists i need to
   //throw an error saying mobile number doesnt exist within the dictionary
   //iv been looking at linq statements for the past hour and im confused :(
}
```

Can any one help me on a quick solution for this?

Comment: You don't need LINQ here, but unless you give *some* information about the structure of the dictionary how can anyone answer this?

Comment: Side note, it's useless to instantiate the Dictionary if then the following line you assign it to the result of your method, if your real code is like that then just declare it and remove the `new` part.

Answer (score 3):

There is no point using LINQ here. Use `ContainsKey` or `ContainsValue` instead.

```
if (!GTNMobilelist.ContainsValue(txtmobileNumber.Text))
    ShowErrorMessage();
```

Answer (score 0):

Next time, post your code so far, then we can point out any errors.

It is not clear to me if the phone number is in the key or in the value, but something like this should work.

Check by key:

```
string phoneNumberToLookFor = "12345678";
bool phoneNumberExists = GTNMobilelist.Any(kvp => kvp.Key == phoneNumberToLookFor);
```

Or, check by value:

```
string phoneNumberToLookFor = "12345678";
bool phoneNumberExists = GTNMobilelist.Any(kvp => kvp.Value == phoneNumberToLookFor);
```